# Relationship between the water ionization constant and ionic strength

Tags: equilibrium, water, aqueous-solution, ph, ions

I read in a textbook that

> the water ionization constant ($K_\mathrm{w}$) increases as the ionic strength of the solution increases

and it confused me. If the ionic strength increased, then the activity of each of the ions $\ce{H3O+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ would decrease, leading to a decrease in the value of $K_\mathrm{w}$.

Can someone please explain the mistake in my way of thinking?

Comment: Mother Nature is not always easy to understand.
I am afraid that your textbook is telling the truth.
I have not yet understood all the details myself, but here is a link and a reference that perhaps can enlighten us both: http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/water_dissociation.html#prod T. Vilarifio and M. E. Sastre de Vicente, J. Solution Chem. 26 (1997) 833-846. Theoretical calculations of the ionic strength dependence of the ionic product of water based on a mean spherical approximation.

Answer (score 4):

The [equilibrium constant](http://goldbook.iupac.org/html/E/E02177.html) is given though $$K_x = \prod_{\ce{B}} x_{\ce{B}}^{\nu_{\ce{B}}},$$
where $x$ is a specific quantity. We can choose that to be the activity $a$.

For the auto-ionisation
$$\ce{H2O (aq) <=>[H2O] H+ (aq) + OH- (aq)}\tag{1}\label{water}$$ 
we find therefore
$$K_a = \frac{a(\ce{H+})\cdot a(\ce{OH-})}{a(\ce{H2O})}.$$

Assuming the equilibrium $\eqref{water}$ is largely on the left side and therefore there is an excess of water, a reasonable simplification is to treat $a(\ce{H2O})$ as constant.
$$K_a' = K_a\cdot a(\ce{H2O}) = a(\ce{H+})\cdot a(\ce{OH-})$$

In ideally diluted solutions we also find
$$\lim_{c\to0}\gamma_i = \frac{a_i}{c_i}=1,$$
and therefore 
$$K_c = c(\ce{H+})\cdot c(\ce{OH-}) \overset{\mathrm{def}}{=} K_\mathrm{w}.$$

The [ionic strength](http://goldbook.iupac.org/html/I/I03180.html) is defined as
$$I_c = \frac12\sum_{\ce{B}}c_{\ce{B}}z_{\ce{B}}^2,$$
or for our case
$$I_{c,\mathrm{w}} = \frac12 \bigg[c(\ce{H+}) + c(\ce{OH-})\bigg].$$

Because of $\eqref{water}$ we can write
$$I_{c,\mathrm{w}} = c(\ce{H+})$$
and
$$K_\mathrm{w} = c(\ce{H+})^2, $$
therefore
$$I_{c,\mathrm{w}} = \sqrt{K_\mathrm{w}}.$$

From this relation you can see, that when $K_\mathrm{w}$ increases, the ionic strength also increases, vice versa.

> If the ionic strength increased, then the activity of each of the ions $\ce{H3O+}$ and $\ce{OH−}$ would decrease, leading to a decrease in the value of $K_\mathrm{w}$.

The first part is correct, the activity of *each* ion would decrease. However, there are more ions, so the activity of the ensemble increases more (given ideal dilution), therefore also leading to an increase in $K_\mathrm{w}$.

Comment: "The first part is correct" I don't see how.